# System call "syscall" instruction in the MIPS architecture

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls

Today I would like to ask you a question. Namely, as a beginner assembly language programmer (and not only that), I would like to ask about the "syscall" instructions in the MIPS architecture. The question reads in more detail as follows:
"What is this syscall instruction? What does its result depend on?" For now, all I know is that "syscall" is a system call. It prints, for example, the value entered by the user. What else?

I have searched various websites on the Internet and even documentation, but it doesn't tell me much so far.

Comment: You know the syscall instruction doesn't do much, but software that runs as a result is like a function call, so can do anything before returning & resuming control to the invoking program?